# Use pandas.concat instead. FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary and an empty dataframe. I was trying to append the dictionary to the pandas dataframe but I got this warning.

I tried this:

```
dict = {
    'city_name': 'Ixelles',
    'type_of_property': 0,
    'price': 0,
    'number_of_rooms':2, 
    'house_area':120, 
    'fully_equipped_kitchen':1,
    'open_fire':0,
    'terrace':1,
    'garden':0, 
    'surface_of_the_land':120,
    'number_of_facades':1,
    'swimming_pool':0,
    'as new':0,
    'good':0,
    'just renovated':1,
    'to be done up':0,
    'to renovate':0,
    'to restore':0,
    'unknown':0
    }
df_predict = df_predict.append(dict, ignore_index = True)
```

But I got this warning:
FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.

I also tried this:

```
df_predict = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
```

but I got this error then:

```
If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are dicts appending in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list, for dictionary dont use `dict` name, because code word in python:

```
df_predict = pd.DataFrame([di])
print (df_predict)
  city_name  type_of_property  price  number_of_rooms  house_area  \
0   Ixelles                 0      0                2         120   

   fully_equipped_kitchen  open_fire  terrace  garden  surface_of_the_land  \
0                       1          0        1       0                  120   

   number_of_facades  swimming_pool  as new  good  just renovated  \
0                  1              0       0     0               1   

   to be done up  to renovate  to restore  unknown  
0              0            0           0        0
```